# Searching for a keyboard optimized webbrowser (ideally on Linux)

Tags: linux, web-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

So we all know most webbrowsers are highly optimized for mouse usage. Basically every button on the web screams "use your mouse".
I've always used mouse a decent amount until I began using Linux. I don't use it as much now - with the Terminal running in the background constantly and me mostly using my PC to edit or view variations of text files it's just not necessary.

As such, I'm wondering if there are any keyboard optimized webbrowsers out there. I would imagine it to be quite difficult to design such a browser, but not impossible  - for example, most buttons that link to some site have some kind of text written on them, and even if they don't, there's still the *actual* link that's plaintext and that could somehow be displayed instead of the button. Maybe navigating through webpages and clicking on links could be emulated on the keyboard by making it possible to do a regex search on the part of the website that's currently on screen and in that way jump from link to link.

Googling for things like this is quite difficult (mostly because any combination of "keyboard" and "webbrowser" just leads to search results for keyboard shortcuts). I've heard of Lynx, but it seems this browser's concept mostly stems from being able to see the web like a crawler does and although I would imagine it has quite a lot of keyboard shortcuts, given that it runs in the Terminal, it's not really what I'm looking for.

Does anybody know any browsers or browser plugins that make traversing the web with keyboard just as efficient (or even more efficient) than with mouse?

Comment: Not tried myself, but it screams for e.g. [Vimb](https://fanglingsu.github.io/vimb/) or [xombrero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xombrero). If those go too far for you, the [Vimperator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimperator) or [Pentadactyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadactyl_%28extension%29) Firefox extensions might be worth a look.

Comment: PS: Would be nice if you'd let us know when you checked those. If one of them fits your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://qutebrowser.org/

> qutebrowser is a keyboard-focused browser with a minimal GUI. It’s based on Python and PyQt5 and free software, licensed under the GPL.
>
> It was inspired by other browsers/addons like dwb and 
>   Vimperator/Pentadactyl.

Quick overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2RtjO_jXvY